# How did Daisy survive this?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In the season finale, when Daisy and Talbot are fighting, Talbot grabs Daisy.

> He then zooms thousands of feet into the air (well above the skyscrapers of Chicago, then smashes back downward hard enough to leave a *crater*.

Daisy is battered and scratched (and possibly has some internal injuries, who knows), but is alive and conscious.

To a lesser extent, this also occurs when she tackles Talbot, knocking him a hundred feet or so back, and hard enough to tear up the pavement, but is (in this case) *completely* unharmed.

All this was *before* taking the Centipede serum, which definitely did...something.

Previously, Daisy has seemed to have normal durability, being susceptible to edged weapons, bullets, and so forth. She's been shot or beaten up by regular people, for instance, subsequent to activating her powers.

Why did she suffer so little injury?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She used her powers to soften the impact.

In Season 4 Episode 8 we saw her launch herself into the air in after absorbing the vibrations from Eli Morrow's quantum energy device, and that she used her powers to land without injury from skyscraper height creating some damage to where she landed - so we know she is capable of cushioning a fall.

Mark Kolpack (VFX supervisor for AoS) posted the VFX boards for the drop on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/MarkKolpack/status/1010185594738114561) that show she created a "quake ball" just before hitting the ground to allow her to survive the impact:

[image: VFX Boards of Daisy dropping from the sky]

Comment: I think you're right, but that looks like the shockwave from the impact.

Comment: @Adamant Yeah, it does a bit, although if you look at the penultimate board the "quake ball" is there as a whole ball before/as she hits the ground. When I next rewatch the episode I'm going to pay more attention to this sequence - it's implied on Twitter that the VFX for the "quake ball" are mixed in with the debris and therefore easy to miss.